# How to save and read data from Session?

Tags: java, playframework

I'm using `play framework 2.8.x` and I trying to save data into the session and in the next request read this data but my data not saved in the session object. My controller class looks like the following:

```
public class UserController extends Controller {
    public Result verifyToken(Http.Request request) {
        final Http.Session session = request.session();
        session.adding("key1", "my_value");
        return ok(userInfo).withCookies(tokenCookie).withSession(session);
    }
}
```

then I refactoring my code like the following:

```
public class UserController extends Controller {
    public Result verifyToken(Http.Request request) {
        return ok(userInfo).addingToSession(request, "sessionData", "test");
    }
}
```

but I have the same result. Not working!
and then I trying to read my data from the session in the `Filter`. My filter looks like the following:

```
public class PageAccessFilter extends Filter {
    @Inject
    public PageAccessFilter(Materializer mat) {
        super(mat);
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> apply(Function<Http.RequestHeader, CompletionStage<Result>> next, Http.RequestHeader rh) {
        final Http.Session userSession = rh.session();
            final String userToken = userSession.get("key1").orElse(null); // in this value was null.
        return next(rh);
    }
}
```

[image]
How can I save and read data from the session? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addingToSession` on the ok() response.

```
public class UserController extends Controller {
    public Result verifyToken(Http.Request request) {
        return ok(userInfo).addingToSession(request, "key1", "my_value");
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not working for me. I don't understand what is happened with sessions in ```play framework```

Comment: @John This should be working. Keep in mind that the session value will appear in the filter only on subsequent requests. Not the one where you are adding it. Please post your full project to github and I can have a look.

Comment: thanks for the help! I realize my mistake. I'm using ```play framework``` as a backend and ```angular``` for a frontend and my frontend and backend work on different ports and frontend requesting to the server-side as a REST service and that is why my session not stores on the server-side. But I don't realize how to store data on the server-side in my case when beckend is a just REST service.